# corosync immediately shuts down after start

Tags: cluster-computing, pacemaker

I am running a pacemaker cluster with corosync on two nodes.
I had to restart node2 and after reboot and doing

```
service corosync start
```

corosync is started but shuts down itself immediately.

After the log entry "Completed service synchronization, ready to provide service." there is an entry "Node was shut down by a signal" and the shutdown starts.

This is the complete log output:

```
notice  [MAIN  ] Corosync Cluster Engine ('2.3.4'): started and ready to 
provide service.
info    [MAIN  ] Corosync built-in features: debug testagents augeas systemd pie relro bindnow
warning [MAIN  ] member section is deprecated.
warning [MAIN  ] Please migrate config file to nodelist.
notice  [TOTEM ] Initializing transport (UDP/IP Unicast).
notice  [TOTEM ] Initializing transmit/receive security (NSS) crypto: none hash: none
notice  [TOTEM ] Initializing transport (UDP/IP Unicast).
notice  [TOTEM ] Initializing transmit/receive security (NSS) crypto: none hash: none
notice  [TOTEM ] The network interface [192.168.1.102] is now up.
notice  [SERV  ] Service engine loaded: corosync configuration map access [0]
info    [QB    ] server name: cmap
notice  [SERV  ] Service engine loaded: corosync configuration service [1]
info    [QB    ] server name: cfg
notice  [SERV  ] Service engine loaded: corosync cluster closed process group service v1.01 [2]
info    [QB    ] server name: cpg
notice  [SERV  ] Service engine loaded: corosync profile loading service [4]
notice  [QUORUM] Using quorum provider corosync_votequorum
notice  [VOTEQ ] Waiting for all cluster members. Current votes: 1 expected_votes: 2
notice  [SERV  ] Service engine loaded: corosync vote quorum service v1.0 [5]
info    [QB    ] server name: votequorum
notice  [SERV  ] Service engine loaded: corosync cluster quorum service v0.1 [3]
info    [QB    ] server name: quorum
notice  [TOTEM ] The network interface [x.x.x.3] is now up.
notice  [TOTEM ] adding new UDPU member {x.x.x.3}
notice  [TOTEM ] adding new UDPU member {x.x.x.2}
warning [TOTEM ] Incrementing problem counter for seqid 1 iface x.x.x.3 to [1 of 10]
notice  [TOTEM ] A new membership (192.168.1.102:7420) was formed. Members joined: -1062731418
notice  [VOTEQ ] Waiting for all cluster members. Current votes: 1 expected_votes: 2
notice  [VOTEQ ] Waiting for all cluster members. Current votes: 1 expected_votes: 2
notice  [VOTEQ ] Waiting for all cluster members. Current votes: 1 expected_votes: 2
notice  [QUORUM] Members[1]: -1062731418
notice  [MAIN  ] Completed service synchronization, ready to provide service.
notice  [MAIN  ] Node was shut down by a signal
notice  [SERV  ] Unloading all Corosync service engines.
info    [QB    ] withdrawing server sockets
notice  [SERV  ] Service engine unloaded: corosync vote quorum service v1.0
info    [QB    ] withdrawing server sockets
notice  [SERV  ] Service engine unloaded: corosync configuration map access
info    [QB    ] withdrawing server sockets
notice  [SERV  ] Service engine unloaded: corosync configuration service
info    [QB    ] withdrawing server sockets
notice  [SERV  ] Service engine unloaded: corosync cluster closed process group service v1.01
info    [QB    ] withdrawing server sockets
notice  [SERV  ] Service engine unloaded: corosync cluster quorum service v0.1
notice  [SERV  ] Service engine unloaded: corosync profile loading service
notice  [MAIN  ] Corosync Cluster Engine exiting normally
```

Comment: I also setup a completely clean openSUSE 13.2 virtual machine and corosync is also shutdown in this clean environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with openSUSE 13.2.

Since this version you can find the line

```
StopWhenUnneeded=yes
```

in the file

```
/usr/lib/systemd/system/corosync.service
```

which controls the service via "service corosync start/stop/etc".
If you do not have the service enabled it will automatically be stopped after the manual start. The solution is to enable the service.
I did not enable it until now because I always started the service manually but since the upgrade to 13.2 it is neccessary.